# Read an image from file in C++ and pass to the DrawImage method of Libharu

Tags: c++, libharu

I am using LibHaru libraries to generate a Pdf report. In this report, I have to draw an image also. The image is present in a file (could be .jpg, .png, .JPEG).

How can I safely get the data of this image and pass to the `HPDF_Page_DrawImage(HPDF_Page page, HPDF_Image image, HPDF_REAL x, HPDF_REAL y, HPDF_REAL width, HPDF_REAL height);` method of LibHaru?

**PS:** I don't want to use other libraries (like opencv, libpng etc.) only to read the image. LibHaru also provides two different methods to load an image from file i.e. `HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile()` and `HPDF_LoadRawImageFromFile(HPDF_Doc pdf, const char *filename, HPDF_UINT width, HPDF_UINT height, HPDF_ColorSpace color_space)`. The disadvantage with `HPDF_LoadRawImageFromFile()` is that you need to know the `width` and `height` of the image to be loaded beforehand which is not possible in my case.

**UPDATE:** I tried to use `HPDF_Image Image = HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile(pdf, "E:/images/logo.png");` but that results in the following linker error in VS21010

`LibHaru.lib(hpdf_image_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_set_strip_16 referenced in function LoadPngData`

Comment: Yes, i already had a look at that method. But with this method, I am not able to extract the details about image (its height, width, data).

Comment: Ah I removed my comments I was going to write them as an answer... I'll do more research on that then.

Comment: What data are you trying to get from the image other then its width and height?

Comment: I need width, Height, Pointer to image data, number of channel, Type (i.e. uint, int etc).

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the examples at:

https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Examples

There is an example for loading an image, and gettings its data, I explicitly looked at the png_demo.c file which has the following example:

```
image = HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile (pdf, filename1);

/* Draw image to the canvas. */
HPDF_Page_DrawImage (page, image, x, y, HPDF_Image_GetWidth (image),
                HPDF_Image_GetHeight (image));
```

There is an entire documentation for LibHaru at:
https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Installation

the HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile method returns the HPDF_Image of the file, which may be the closest you will get to getting a pointer to the image, on their documentation the functions they have available for retrieving information about the image such as its width, height, and bits per component are located on this page:
https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/API%3A-Image

That is the most I can offer without using another library.

Comment: I tried to use `HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile()` but it results in linker error. Please check my UPDATE

Comment: @skm Are you linking to the correct library files in your project settings?

`libhpdf.lib (for release builds) and libhpdfd.lib (for debug builds).`